# squish mp3 file to set duration

Tags: node.js, mp3

I have a mp3 file(around 7 mins) and I want to shorten the file to 1 minute. But I don't want to just cut it. I want to squish the file without changing the pitch(like speed up).

I already tried with FFmpeg, but FFmpeg just cuts it off.

For info: The file is stored in the fs.

Answer (score 0):

This *is* doable with ffmpeg. Try using the atempo filter like this:

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp3 -filter:a "atempo=7.0" -vn seven-times-as-fast.mp3
```

It should produce a new mp3 file in the same pitch, just seven times faster.